# Vue.js. ссылки с href="#anchor" перезагружают страницу

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Проект на vue-cli2, подключен vue-router

Ссылки приходят в контенте от сервера, по запросу, например <a href="#block1"...
при клике по ним, вместо прокрутки до нужного блока, происходит перезагрузка страницы

- как сделать рабочими стандартные якоря в обычных ссылках?
- как сформировать из обычных ссылок router-link, чтобы не было перезагрузки страницы при клике по ним?

Answer (score 0):

Vue не понимает обращение `#block1`,

```
<a @click="anchor('block1')">test</a>
```

`block1` это наименование `ref` элемента на который ведет сам якорь

```
anchor(link) {
    var element = this.$refs[link];
    var top = element.offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }
```

и на элементе на который нужен спуск укажи `ref`

`<span ref="block1"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы используете `vue-router` [в режиме hash](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode). Стандартные якори в этом случае не будут работать. Есть несколько вариантов для решения проблемы:

1. Использовать через `@click` метод:

   ```
    <a @click="scrollMeTo('test')">Test</a>
    <div ref="test">...</div>
    ...
    methods: {
      scrollMeTo(ref) {
          window.scrollTo(0, this.$refs[ref].offsetTop);
      }
    }
   ```
2. Переопределить [ScrollBehavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) в роутере:

   ```
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return { selector: to.hash }
        } else if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Использовать пакет [vue-scrollto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto).